# Why is $a$ not coercive when it is defined on $H^1(\Omega)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, poissons-equation

Given the Poisson's equation with homogeneous Neumann boundary conditions and the associated bilinear form
$$a(u,v) = \int_{\Omega}\nabla u \cdot \nabla v \, dx$$ on $H^1(\Omega)$, why is $a$ not coercive? Whereever I look it says we need $H_0^1(\Omega)$ for coercivity, but I am not sure why $H^1(\Omega)$ wouldn't work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because $1 \in H^1(\Omega)$ and $a(1,1) = 0$. Here, $1$ is the constant function with value $1$ everywhere.

Comment: Thanks. But isnt $a(1,1)=\int 0 \, dx = const? $

Comment: No, you have $\int_\Omega 0 \, \mathrm{d}x$ and this is $0$.

Comment: Oops, I mixed it up with $\int 0 dx = const$